# How to disable unnecessary modules in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2-esb

I would like to disable unnecessary modules like SOLR, multi tenanat OR any other until unless they are used internally by WSO2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the unnecessary features via Feature Management section. Find more details [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Managing+Features).